# Find common keys of an array and an object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays with similar values. What I want is to get the intersection of the arrays and object -

The `console.log` of first object is -

```
{  
   "1221":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1222":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1223":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1224":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

The `console.log` of second array is -

```
[["1222","1223","1224"]]
```

So basically, I want to get the first object with ids which is equal to second array, which is 1222, 1223, and 1224.

I have tried using `inArray` but it is not working.

Comment: please add the wanted result - and what you have tried.

Comment: first one is an object and not an array.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal yes Object, sorry my mistake updated question.

Comment: And the second one is array of array. Is this desired or a typo?

Comment: @NinaScholz basically the output will be the first object values with 1222,1223, 1224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let obj = {"1221":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1222":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1223":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1224":{"oldPrice":{"amount":80},"basePrice":{"amount":80},"finalPrice":{"amount":80},"tierPrices":[]}};

let arr = [["1222","1223","1224"]];

let result = arr[0].reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c] : obj[c]}), {});
console.log(result);
```

**Note**: In case there is an entry in `array` which is missing in `object`, you can update the code to following

```js
let obj = {"1221":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1222":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1223":{"oldPrice":{"amount":75},"basePrice":{"amount":75},"finalPrice":{"amount":75},"tierPrices":[]},"1224":{"oldPrice":{"amount":80},"basePrice":{"amount":80},"finalPrice":{"amount":80},"tierPrices":[]}};

let arr = [["missing_entry_from_obj", "1222","1223","1224"]];

let result = arr[0].reduce((a,c) => {if(obj[c]) a[c]= obj[c]; return a;}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: {1222,1223,1224: undefined} is the output. The keys are correct, but why undefined?

Comment: @Tester - I can not find undefined in the output. Are you running the code on different input? Is it possible that an entry exists in array but not in object? Only this scenario can lead to undefined value

Comment: There is an array with 1220, 1219 etcc obj. But that should not matter, right?

Comment: No. Check my updated answer. It should fix it for extra items in array

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map to work:

```js
var a1 = {  
   "1221":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1222":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1223":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":75
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   },
   "1224":{  
      "oldPrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "basePrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "finalPrice":{  
         "amount":80
      },
      "tierPrices":[  

      ]
   }
};
var a2 = [["1222","1223","1224"]];
var result = {};
a2[0].map(current=>{
    var temp = a1[current];
    result[current] = temp;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map either the existent object or false, if not found. Then create a new object of the parts.

```js
var object = { 1221: { oldPrice: { amount: 75 }, basePrice: { amount: 75 }, finalPrice: { amount: 75 }, tierPrices: [] }, 1222: { oldPrice: { amount: 75 }, basePrice: { amount: 75 }, finalPrice: { amount: 75 }, tierPrices: [] }, 1223: { oldPrice: { amount: 75 }, basePrice: { amount: 75 }, finalPrice: { amount: 75 }, tierPrices: [] }, 1224: { oldPrice: { amount: 80 }, basePrice: { amount: 80 }, finalPrice: { amount: 80 }, tierPrices: [] } },
    keys = ["1222", "1223", "1224"],
    result = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => k in object && { [k]: object[k] }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```